# how to add items to a cardView without recycle view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I have a blank card view and need to add items to this cardView in the layout detailed below.

```
----------------------------
|image|"text here"   
|image|"text here"   |image|
----------------------------
```

[image: more detailed version of above]

the problem i am having is all of the tutorial etc start talking about recycleviews etc when i just want to add items to my cardView.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why not just create your own custom view?

Comment: so dont use cardview at all?

Comment: You can create a custom view to look just about any way you want. What is it about the `CardView` that you want to emulate? They are basically just a View that is placed inside a `RecyclerView` to give them a standardized look. They are pretty much useless anywhere else.

Comment: CardView is a simple ViewGroup. Put any Layout inside it and use as a simple VIew.

Answer (score 1):

try this layout for your `cardview`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

note that you should complete the other attributes.
this layout is used for one item. and if you have data to display them, you can use a `RecyclerView`.

check out this [Tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/?utm_source=recyclerview&utm_medium=site&utm_campaign=refer_article) for more informations.